# Comparing elapsed time to copy memory buffers: memcpy vs ForLoopIndexCopying

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, memcpy

I am trying to understand the difference between "memcpy" and "for-loop-index-copying" of a buffer in the time it takes to copy.

```
results:  
          CopyingType  |  MemoryType  |  RunMode  |  Elapsed Time(ms)
          -----------------------------------------------------------
             memcpy    |    stack     |   Debug   |          x   
       forLoopIndexing |    stack     |   Debug   |        30x
             memcpy    |    stack     |   Release |          0   
       forLoopIndexing |    stack     |   Release |          0
             memcpy    |    heap      |   Release |          0   
       forLoopIndexing |    heap      |   Release |       2000
```

Here is my code to run... Maybe I am doing something wrong ???

Seems odd that to copy a 500,000 byte buffer 100,000 times takes no time at all or at least less than the resolution of the machine... in my case 16ms.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  long baseTime;

  const long packetLength = 500000;
  //char packet1[packetLength];//stack
  //char packet2[packetLength];//stack
  char *packet1 = (char*)calloc(packetLength, sizeof(char));//heap
  char *packet2 = (char*)calloc(packetLength, sizeof(char));//heap
  memset(packet1, 0, packetLength);//init
  memset(packet2, 0, packetLength);//init
  long NumPackets = 100000;
  long NumRuns = 10;


  for (long k = 0; k < NumRuns; k++)
  {
    //create packet
    printf("\npacket1:\n");
    for (long i = 0; i < packetLength; i++) {
      packet1[i] = (char)(i % 26 + 65);
    }

    printf("\nk:%d\n", k);

    //index copy
    baseTime = GetTickCount();
    long ii = 0;
    for (long j = 0; j < NumPackets; j++) {
      for (long i = 0; i < packetLength; i++) {
        packet2[i] = packet1[i];
      }
    }
    printf("Time(IndexCopy): %ld\n", GetTickCount() - baseTime);


    //memcpy
    memset(packet2, 0, packetLength);//reset

    baseTime = GetTickCount();
    for (long j = 0; j < NumPackets; j++) {
      memcpy(packet2, packet1, packetLength); //Changed via PaulMcKenzie.
    }
    printf("Time(memcpy): %ld\n", GetTickCount() - baseTime);


    //printf("\npacket2\n");
    for (long i = 0; i < packetLength; i++) {
      //printf("%c", packet2[i]);
    }

  }
  int iHalt;
  scanf_s("%d", &iHalt);

  return 0;
}
```

---

Via the change... the new table

```
          CopyingType  |  MemoryType  |  RunMode  |  Elapsed Time(ms)
          -----------------------------------------------------------
             memcpy    |    stack     |   Debug   |          x   
       forLoopIndexing |    stack     |   Debug   |        50x
             memcpy    |    stack     |   Release |          0   
       forLoopIndexing |    stack     |   Release |          0
             memcpy    |    heap      |   Release |       2000   
       forLoopIndexing |    heap      |   Release |       2000
```

Comment: Check the assembly code, might have optimised out.

Comment: `memcpy(packet2, packet1, sizeof(packet2));` -- This does not do what you think it does.  What is `sizeof(packet2)`, given that `packet2` is a `char *`?

Comment: http://quick-bench.com/P_Q4UVitmDw1B1xTdye1iBskfSo

Comment: @A.A -- I think you need to update your code so that you're not making similar mistakes with the 3rd argument to `memcpy` that the OP is making.

Comment: Impressive bench testing

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, fixed. Looks better. http://quick-bench.com/BnJz8JrbrXPTqYWdjfaXZ_IIMvM I wanted to try it out :)

Comment: @A.A -- Yes, the fixed version, when the code is corrected, does show that the stack version does not give 0 as the time.

Comment: With the change to placing the length of the buffer in Memcpy,  I still get "0 time" for the STACK for both ForLoopIndexCopying and Memcpy

Comment: @jdl I hope you didn't made my mistake - not `sizeof(packetLength)`?

Comment: I modified the code... you can see

Comment: The generated code more than likely optimized away that loop since it detects you're not doing anything with those arrays.  If you actually did something with `packet1` and `packet2`, maybe print their contents (outside of the timing block), then you may get the desired results.  Compiler optimizers are smart in this day and age -- just because you have a `GetTickCount` call doesn't mean the compiler will know what your intent was with that call.  You do nothing with variables, you get nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Maybe I am doing something wrong ???

You are doing something wrong, more to the point, in the code that uses `memcpy`.

```
const long packetLength = 500000;
char *packet1 = (char*)calloc(packetLength, sizeof(char));
char *packet2 = (char*)calloc(packetLength, sizeof(char));    
//...
for (long j = 0; j < NumPackets; j++) {
      memcpy(packet2, packet1, sizeof(packet2)); // <-- Incorrect
    }
```

The `sizeof(packet2)` is the same as `sizeof(char *)`, which more than likely is either 4 or 8.

What you want is not the `sizeof(char *)`, but the actual number of bytes to copy.

```
for (long j = 0; j < NumPackets; j++) {
      memcpy(packet2, packet1, packetLength);
    }
```

Comment: But the ForLoopIndexCopying will yield "0" time as well if the memory is that on the STACK.

Comment: Your `memcpy` is still wrong, regardless of the final result.  You asked if you were doing anything wrong, and yes, you are.

Comment: Yes for the Heap memory and memcpy this applies... but what about the Stack memory... the commented out code?  I get 0 time for both indexing and memcpy.